# Button for locknow() method

Tags: android, locking

I need simple app where I have button which open lockscreen at my device - nothing more.

So I created button...

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/lockbutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
    android:text="lock"
    android:onClick="locking" />
```

...and method

```
public void locking(View button) {
    DevicePolicyManager mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
    mDPM.lockNow();
}
```

But when I click on button, the app crashes. Have anyone an idea?

Comment: Can you post stack trace?

Comment: `lockNow()` does not open the lockscreen. It locks the device.

Comment: In this case it does not matter. ;-) ... It should be a small authentication application.

Comment: Then, with respect to your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this